# How to hook up swagger-ui

Tags: java, swagger

I'm trying to hook in swagger-ui into a java dynamic web project. Currently, the rest api works and I am able to hit the following url and see the json: http://localhost:8080/test/swagger.json

My project uses Java, Swagger, Wildfly, and RestEasy.

```
public class SwaggerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);

        BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
        beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
        beanConfig.setSchemes(new String[] { "http" });
        beanConfig.setHost("localhost:8080");
        beanConfig.setBasePath("/test");
        beanConfig.setResourcePackage("com.test.rest");
        beanConfig.setScan(true);
    }
}
```

Following the tutorial found at this link: http://kjkrol.blogspot.ca/2015/01/how-to-integrate-swagger-ui-with-java.html to hook up swagger ui doesn't seem to work for me. I downloaded swagger-ui repo from github. I created a swagger folder in the following location:

my-project/src/main/webapp/swagger

In the swagger folder, copied the dist folder from the swagger-ui project. I also edited the URL as the tutorial suggests:

```
  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "test/api-docs",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
```

Comment: what do you see when you go to that URL? anything?

Comment: @Hack-R http://localhost:8080/test/api-docs: nothing, blank page

Comment: You can follow from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bgzWvbvERV4&t=85s

Comment: @RameshKC unfortunately, i'm not using spring, so my setup looks different, thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: If you are able to call http://localhost:8080/test/swagger.json and get the response than its working. To view UI try to call http://localhost:8080/test/index.html and check whether its showing the UI page of swagger or not, If not than you may be missing something.

Comment: It should work, maybe a CORS issue, can you check the browser's console, any errors ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following an example found at this link: https://github.com/K0NRAD/swagger-wildfly-resteasy

It works! I noticed that the documentation takes a slightly different approach that for some reason wasn't working for me...

Thanks everyone!